# Spline Set of a font glyph in FontForge

Tags: fonts, postscript, spline, bspline, fontforge

When saving a font with SFD format, the SplineSet looks like

```
388 268 m 1,0,1
 354 357 354 357 285 569 c 1,2,3
 276 546 276 546 239 441 c 128,-1,4
 202 336 202 336 174 268 c 1,5,6
 252 266 252 266 305 266 c 128,-1,7
 358 266 358 266 388 268 c 1,0,
```

which is the same structure as PostScript (when exporting a single glyph)

```
388 268 moveto
 365.333 327.333 331 427.667 285 569 curveto
 279 553.667 263.667 511 239 441 curveto
 214.333 371 192.667 313.333 174 268 curveto
 226 266.667 269.667 266 305 266 curveto
 340.333 266 368 266.667 388 268 curveto
```

Although the start and end points are the same, the control points are not the same in SDF and PostScript, and the latter is correct.

**My question is:** what are the extra three numbers in SFD file? Do they correct the location of control points to be those of PostScript? If yes, how. If no, why are the values of control points different in SFD and PostScript?

I understand that the last two numbers are the TTF point numbers. Only the first number (which is usually, 0, 1, 128, and 256 in my case) after the flags (m/c/l) can correct the position of control points. However, the FontForge SDF File format says

```
0x3 indicates whether the point is curve (0), corner (1) or tangent (2).
0x4 point selected
```

How can I transform the SDF coordinates to actual PostScript points?

Comment: What's your source for the postscript part? Glyphs in PS fonts are typically laid out in a 1000x1000 coordinate space. Maybe the SFD coordinates are in a different space, or quantized differently, or one or the other could have hints applied? If you're using the postscript `charpath` operator, that will definitely be a *post-processed* number that has been quantized to device integers and then `itransform`ed back to user space.